# Is the entire Xss (stack space) used for each Java thread?

Tags: java, regex, stack

I am considering increasing the stack size to work around the [StackOverflowError thrown by the regex library](http://madbean.com/2004/mb2004-20/) which [does not appear to be on the plans for a fix](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5050507).

### Edit: Solution

- [Stephen C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402986/is-the-entire-xss-stack-space-used-for-each-java-thread/4403346#4403346) is probably the best answer to the problem, even if it is not an answer to the question. Although my string size was more than 4k already, I was still likely to eventually have the problem again during the lifetime of the product
- [aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402986/is-the-entire-xss-stack-space-used-for-each-java-thread/4403171#4403171) is the best answer to the actual question, perhaps not the actual problem.
- [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402986/is-the-entire-xss-stack-space-used-for-each-java-thread/4403499#4403499) is a very good idea. **Edit:** [JRegex](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/) worked great!

Comment: Ouch. They could avoid this by using loops with states instead of recursive method calls.

Comment: I wonder if all the regular expressions could be implemented / replaced by "regular" functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution would be to rewrite the regex to avoid the problem.  Or better still, replace it with some plain Java parsing code.  Or maybe just reject strings larger than a certain length.

Bumping the stack size only puts off the problem.  Now you can cope with 2000 or 4000 character input strings instead of 1000.  But sooner or later you are likely to run into one that causes your expanded stacks to overflow.

Comment: (I acknowledge that @GeorgeBailey's edited question says he can cope with 4k character input with the current default stack size.  However, revising my answer would only confuse things.)

Answer (score 5):

> **Is the entire Xss (stack space) used for each Java thread?**

According to [this page](http://www.javamex.com/how_to_fix.html), **yes**:

> - increase the stack size for all threads in your application, by including -Xssnnm in the Java command line (where nn is the number of megabytes of stack space per thread);

You can however choose a larger stack size for a specific thread using the [`Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29) constructor.

> *Allocates a new Thread object so that it has target as its run object, has the specified name as its name, belongs to the thread group referred to by group, and has the specified stack size.*

Note however that (according to documentation) the effect of the `stackSize` parameter, if any, is highly platform dependent and that the value of the `stackSize` parameter may have no effect whatsoever on some platforms.

Comment: Sry I'm not understanding the first paragraph. Do you mean to say that if I set -Xss2m and I have 10 threads, each thread uses 2m = 20m total?, or each thread uses 0.2m = 2m total?

Answer (score 1):

What about using [JRegex](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/) or [Jakarta Regex](http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/index.html) instead?

Comment: I used JRegex for some of the trouble makers and it worked wonders. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If a regex in the form of `(x|ab)*` is causing stack overflows or other crashes in your regex engine (as mentioned in the [madbean.com](http://madbean.com/2004/mb2004-20/) link in the original question) , here are a few tips to rewrite such a regular expression.

The regular expression `(x|ab)*` consists of a capturing group with two alternatives that are mutually exclusive.  This regex can be optimized in 3 ways, depending on the features supported by your regex flavor.  The java.util.regex flavor supports all 3.

The capturing group will store the text matched during its last iteration after a successful match, which is either `x` or `ab`.  Since you probably don't care about the last iteration, you can tell the regex engine that you don't care and use a non-capturing group: `(?:x|ab)*`.  How much of a speed increase this gives depends on how the regex engine keeps track of capturing groups.

The alternatives are mutually exclusive.  If `x` matches, there is no point in trying to match `ab` at the same position.  You can tell the regex engine that by using an atomic group: `(?>x|ab)*`  Atomic groups are non-capturing, so this preserves the previous optimization.

Your repeated group `(?>x|ab)*` is not followed by anything that could match the same text as `x` or `ab`.  Thus, the quantifier `*` can match as many iterations as possible, without ever having to give back to allow the remainder of the regex to match.  You can tell the regex engine that by using a possessive quantifier: `(?>x|ab)*+`

Depending on how the java.util.regex engine handles backtracking and the suppression thereof via atomic groups and possessive quantifiers, any of these optimizations or the combination of them may very well avoid the stack overflow.  Even if it doesn't and you choose to use a different regex engine, these techniques can still improve the performance of your regular expressions.